# Where should I define data gathering methods in Django

Tags: python, django, api

I am working on a simple music website which gathers data from Last.Fm, MusicBrainz, and others.

So far when I add an Artist (just by name) it gathers all it's albums and songs and saves them. I decided to put this in a customized save method for the Artist.

This process can last up to 2 or 3 minutes using runserver.

I was wondering if this is the "right" place to do all this things, since when I add a new Artist I have to wait for the page to load when it finishes all the gathering.

Is there a better place to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd be much better off doing this sort of task in a background process – one that doesn't block the request/response cycle of HTTP. There's a couple of decent ways to do, you can [write a management command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands/) that you would run via `python manage.py ...`.

However, I strongly suggest you have a look at [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/). There's more overhead initially to get it setup, but it's really a better direction to head in (rather than rolling your own background process stuff).

Comment: Thanks, I will give Celery a try.